# Terraform plan error - Missing Expected {

Tags: terraform

I am using terraform 0.14.3 with custom provider to manage resources on on-perm infrastructure. Things are running fine as long as I am running Terraform to store state locally. However, when I switch to PG as backend, it gives me an error on plan:

```
Error: Missing Expected {
```

Below is how i am using PG configuration:

```
terraform {
   required_providers {
       mycloud = {
         source = "terraform.provider/proj/cloud"
         version = "0.0.x"
      }
   }

  backend "pg" {
       conn_str = "postgres://connection.url.for.postgres"
  }
}
```

Again if remove the backend config, it works fine.

Comment: Is the PSQL DB already created? If not, you have to create it first: https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/settings/backends/pg.html#example-configuration.

Comment: It's already there with all the necessary permissions.

Comment: Did you rerun `terraform init` after changing the backend?

Comment: Yes, it runs fine. I can see it successfully switching to backend mode with PG in logs.

Comment: not sure if this will help but have you tried running `terraform fmt` and `terraform validate`?

Comment: have done `terraform validate`, it runs fine with success. tried `terraform fmt` now, running fine. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that this code is fully representative of your real code?

Comment: Surely there are several resource blocks and the whole provider itself. But this is where I put backend, and it stops working. As I said earlier, everything works just fine without this backend block. Please let me know if you think some specific code block might have caused this, i'll put that code here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem.  My debugging consisted of downloading the unhealthy tfstate and deleting resources until it started working again, which identified the broken resource.  Then when I found the errant resource depicted below, I compared it to another healthy workspace :

```
{
  "module": "module.mongodb_project",
  "mode": "managed",
  "type": "mongodbatlas_cloud_provider_access",
  "name": "encryption_access",
  "provider": "provider[\"registry.terraform.io/mongodb/mongodbatlas\"]",
  "instances": [
    {
      "schema_version": 0,
      "attributes": {
        "atlas_assumed_role_external_id": "48491470-626e-4091-8b5e-..........",
        "atlas_aws_account_arn": "arn:aws:iam::536727724300:root",
        "authorized_date": "2021-04-19T18:40:22Z",
        "created_date": "2021-03-12T18:51:17Z",
        "feature_usages": [
          {
            "feature_id": "",     <<<< ==== THIS IS THE PROBLEM
            "feature_type": "ENCRYPTION_AT_REST"
          }
        ],
        "iam_assumed_role_arn": "arn:aws:iam::2411360.....:role/bluescape-kms",
        "id": "...",
        "project_id": "604bb8221347fxxxxxxxxxx",
        "provider_name": "AWS",
        "role_id": "604bb82577962xxxxxxxxxx"
      },
      "sensitive_attributes": [],
      "private": "xxxxxxxx",
      "dependencies": [
        "module.mongodb_project.mongodbatlas_project.project"
      ]
    }
  ]
},
```

In my healthy workspace, "feature_id" is {}, whereas in this unhealthy workspace, "feature_id" is "".  Apparently, when there is a schema upgrade to a new version of a provider, they sometimes forget to run a conversion on the data and so this error represents a failure to upgrade the data structure from "" to {} (map).  It is also happening for another resource of mine in the same workspace but I have to convert {} -> null!

Terraform should do a better job of printing errors when it encounters an error in tfstate.  We have never edited the tfstate for this workspace before, the error is a result of schema upgrades that were not properly implemented by the mongo backend-provider developer.

Comment: Thanks for this same happened to us on one of the clusters when we updated the provider

    mongodbatlas = {
      source  = "mongodb/mongodbatlas"
    - version = "~> 0.9.1"
    + version = "~> 1.0.1"
    }